# PHP - Convert Returned Value From wp-function to String

Tags: php, html, string, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress' CMS for my website, I want to display recent blog posts, but without the HTML tags which are within the post. I have tried the following, but to no avail.

```
$content = the_content();
$content = strval($content);
echo strip_tags($content, '<p><a>');
```

Which returns the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'the_content' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp\wp-content\themes\My-theme\index.php on line 25
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`the_content()` will directly echo your content so you are getting the error. Try

```
$content = get_the_content(); //returns the content so your $content will have all the contents
$content = strval($content);
echo strip_tags($content, '<p><a>');
```